# giving names to threads used by apache httpcomponents

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using httpcomponents 4.3.3 to do posts. I would like to name the threads it uses so I can easily see them in a thread dump. Is it possible? I see there's a way to wrap an HttpClient in a FutureRequestExecutionService, and give that a ThreadFactory that will provided named threads. Is there another option? I'm currently creating my HttpClient like so:

```
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler(requestRetryHandler).build();
```

Comment: I don't see any threads spawned. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'll try to post a trace

Comment: were using both async http client, and http components. It appears http components doesn't spawn threads the way async http client does (I had confused the two), so using an Executor with a ThreadFactory that names threads does solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

java.lang.Thread has a `setName()` method. If the thread you want to name extends Thread, you can call `setName("myThread")` on  it.

EDIT:
Based on this suggestion, [Alper Akture](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138137/alper-akture) was able to figure out an actual solution.

`ExecutorService` has a constructor that accepts a `ThreadFactory`, and the `ThreadFactory` can be told to create named threads.

Comment: With the library OP is referring to, they do not have direct control over the creation of threads.

Comment: I guess this would actually work. But I don't have a reference to the thread to name it. I'm actually using an executor, guava has a ThreadFactoryBuilder that I will use to created a pool with named threads, something like:  ThreadFactory namedThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("MyHttpClient.thread-%d").build();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(namedThreadFactory);

Comment: So you marked my answer as the solution. Does that mean you found a way to get direct access to the threads?

Comment: Nope, but in my comment above, the ExecutorService has a constructor that takes a ThreadFactory and uses that to (if you tell it to) use named threads. So in essence, it's the same as your answer I suppose. I just didn't have a way to get at the threads directly, which was my main issue.

Comment: Can you edit my answer (or add your own) to show the code you used so others searching for a similar solution can see how you implemented it?

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed your last comment, and I see you already made the edit, thanks.